# How can I "blindly inject" an object variable with arbitrary value?

Tags: swift

For example, I have a variable with type AnyObject. I do not know what class is that. But I want to test, whether if the object can accept specific attribute, and want to assign value to it.

For example, if I have:

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    var containerVc : UIViewController?;
}
```

If I know that a variable can be typecasted into BaseViewController, then, of course, I can just typecast it to BaseViewController, and then assign the variable to it.

```
let vc : UIViewController?;
vc = BaseViewController();
(vc as? BaseViewController)?.containerVc = self;
```

The problem is if the BaseViewController type itself is inaccessible or unknowable.

So what I want to do is that I just want to test if an attribute is available to be set, if the operation can't be performed, it can fail silently. So for example, the code I have in mind if this is possible:

```
var vc : UIViewController? = generateUnknownVc();
vc.setValue(self, forAttribute: "containerVc");
```

or genericaly:

```
var abc : AnyObject = generateRandomObject();
abc.setValue(123, forAttribute: "randomAttribute");
```

I ask this because I remember somewhere that you can supply value to an object the way Storyboard does (User Defined Runtime Attributes). But I don't know how that works programmatically.

**CONCLUSION:**

This is the code I finally ended up with, borrowed heavily from Ehsan Saddique's answer. This code has been improved to also check the ancestors (superclass).

```
extension NSObject {

    func safeValue(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        var copy : Mirror? = Mirror(reflecting: self);
        while copy != nil {
            for child in copy!.children.makeIterator() {
                if let label = child.label, label == key {
                    return child.value
                }
            }
            copy = copy?.superclassMirror;
        }
        return nil
    }

    func setValueSafe(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        if safeValue(forKey: key) != nil { self.setValue(value, forKey: key); }
    }

}
```

And from Andreas Oetjen's answer, I need to make mental note that this only works if the object is descendant from `NSObject` or tagged with `@objc`, and the function is also tagged with `@objc`.

Thanks!

Comment: The design concept of Swift encourages you not to walk *blindly* around while developing software. Be as specific as possible rather than the contrary. Swift is a *take-care-of-types* language. Work with protocols. Let the compiler check at **compile** time if an object responds to methods or has certain properties. Any unnecessary runtime check decreases efficiency and performance.

Comment: @vadian I know that. One of the reason that I love work with Swift is because of its strong typed language. But there are always exception cases. I always try to make those cases as little as possible. But sometimes there are things that when you know all the parameters and risks in a controlled environment, using exception can make a good use case that using normal route can be a hassle or even impossible to achieve instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` is inherited from `NSObject`. You can use Key-Value-Coding to find if the key exists. Add this extension to your code.

```
extension NSObject {
    func safeValue(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        let copy = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in copy.children.makeIterator() {
            if let label = child.label, label == key {
                return child.value
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can use if-let to check if key exists.

```
if let key = yourViewController.safeValue(forKey: "someKey") {
    print("key exists")
    yourViewController.setValue("someValue", forKey:"someKey")
}
else {
    print("key doesn't exist")
}
```

You will have to mark your properties with `@objc` to use KVC.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my answer to show my final code, which largely incorporate your code. Yeah, Key-Value-Coding. I always forgot about that term.

Answer (score 1):

You would use Key-Value-Coding, which is supported in swift if (and only if)

- Your class is somehow a subclass of `NSObject` or tagged with `@objc`
- Your properties you want to access are tagged with `@objc`

I currently have no Xcode available, but this sample code should work:

```
class A : NSObject {
    @objc var name:String = "hello"
}

var theA = A()
theA.setValue("world", forKey:"name")
print(theA.name)  // shoud print "world"
```

To **check** if an property exists (instead of just crashing), see this answer: [Check if class has a value for a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045991/check-if-class-has-a-value-for-a-key)

Comment: If key `name` doesn't exist, this will raise a fatal exception and app will crash.

Comment: I see, the question was how to _detect_ a non-existing key. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the parameter of how to make this work with, especially the `@objc` syntax.